# Docker, Docker-comose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning to create a docker enviroment.

I got stuck on creating  volumes:

after I run the following, I get a DB lock in linux.

```
Volumes:
    - ./data/test:/data/test
```

I tried to run, but sadly it is not working.

```
Volumes:
    - ./data/test:/data/test:rw
```

[image]

Any sugestions ???

Comment: You probably don't have permission to access the folder since it was created by Docker. You can give yourself permission using `chmod`. https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/

Comment: @MarcoBreemhaar yes I use sudo chmod -R 777, but I want a solution so I dont have to use it all the time when I create a new DB.

Comment: I think you should be able to put it in your Dockerfile: `RUN chmod -R 777 /data/test`